# Support XML in Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, xml, database

I am new to Microsoft SQL Server 2014 database.

I'm studying XML support. I realized that it does not support the SQL / XML standard.

Did I get it right?

Thank you

Comment: SQL Server supports xml https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522446.aspx

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/XML, the XML data type in SQL Server has high compliance with the ANSI SQL specification and partial support for SQL/XML predicates and functions.